# Is this a Capture problem? I still can't resolve

Tags: c#, capture

I thought this was a capture issue but nothing I do works. try to simplify here:

```
foreach (Question question in Test.Questions)
{
  int id= question.id;
  if(someIDictionary.TryGetValue(id, out value)
  { 
    question.answerobject.number=someinteger;
  }
  else
  {
    question.answerobject.number=someotherinteger;
  }
}
```

I tried making a temp for question object, but still not working. all results are always last iteration value.

**EDIT:** **Each answerobject is created within each question object as the question is created using linq to sql. then the questions are returned as an IList.**

**EDIT 2: The issue does not occur if I assign values to another field of question. the issue is only with the answerobject.the values of answerobject are same for all questions (the last assignment).**

Comment: Care to explain what you're trying to do? The code isn't immediately obvious.

Comment: if the dictionary has the question ID, i make certain assignment to the answerobject...

Comment: You said you tried to simplify the code for the question... you're not using delegates/lamdas that you're not showing in the simplified version are you?

Comment: @zsharp post more of the code or more information, its hard to tell the problem with the description/info you are giving.

Comment: Can you fix the formatting?  Half my brainpower is trying to figure out how the braces are supposed to line up.

Comment: As others have said, I don't think there is enough detail in the question to sensible answer this. I think the problem has been thrown away during the simplification process...

Comment: "as the question is created using linq to sql" isn't enough (for me) to satisfy "Each answerobject is created within each question object". For example, if the query was wrong, or the DB points the same answer at multiple questions...

Comment: I agree with Marc, might be worth posting your linq to sql code... seems like the answer may lie there. Lots of lambdas in linq, lots of chance for having closure/capture issues.

Comment: take a look at my answer below regarding nullable int. does offer any clues?

Answer (score 2):

What is the problem you are seeing? The "capture" problem only affects async/deferred/threaded code - it shouldn't affect this case.

I wonder if the most likely problem here is that all your `Question` objects have the same `answerobject` instance - or even that you have the same `Question` instance lots of times.

---

illustration of the "capture propblem" (see comments): this is a problem seen when using a lambda/anon-method; if the iteration variable (`question` above) is used in the lambda/anon-method, it is "captured" - but in a slightly counter-intuitive way...

For example; we might expect this to print (in an unpredictable order) the numbers 0-9:

```
int[] vals = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
foreach(int i in vals) {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserItem(delegate {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    });
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

But it doesn't... we fix it by adding an extra variable:

```
int[] vals = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
foreach(int i in vals) {
    int tmp = i;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserItem(delegate {
        Console.WriteLine(tmp);
    });
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

This is because the behaviour of captured variables is determined by their lexical scope... the scope of the iteration variable is a bit larger that we would like.

Comment: What is a "capture" problem ?

Comment: marc see my answer in this thread. does this make more sense?

Comment: I'm sorry, I still can't decipher from the (little) information available.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to occur when answerobject.number (int?) is assigned "Null" when the object is created. If I try to assign a value during the loop i get the issue above. If howwever I assign an integer when the object is created the problem is gone and i can then addign new values during the loop. Can you explain to me cause I dont get it.